# How to show the value of FOR LOOP every second C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

Good day,
it can be the easy question (for everyone) but I don't know how to solve that.

**Simple question - simple answer**.

If I have this code:

```
public void test()
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
          label1.Text = i.ToString();
      }
}
```

If I will call the test method, it writes to me 9999 (surely). I need show on label the variable **i** every second of this loop. I do not want to use a timer - but you can show me a solution with Timer.

What is the easiest way to show LOOP? Excuse me for my English, nice day.

Comment: "I do not want to use a timer." - without a timer. Why?

Comment: Without a timer? Not possible as every machine will have different speeds etc

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.. but you could sleep the Thread every 1000ms.

Comment: Do you want a one second gap between iterations of the loop, or just update the UI every second?

Comment: It is not a homework. Just I think that it's interesting how to show loop. How would it look like with a timer?

Comment: Adam, nice answer. Show iterations.

Comment: @RePRO - you haven't answered Adam's question really. Do you want the for to loop once a second, or loop at it's fastest speed and update the  label's text property every second?

Comment: Hmm, TY @SkonJeet for clarification. :-) I would like to show both variants (ways).

Comment: And why downvote? Great question. Grrr...

Comment: @RePRO - using Thread.Sleep(1000) will give you one way (stalling the iterations for a second), using a timer will provide a way of only updating the UI every second.

Comment: @riffnl - so what? He has to get an answer some how? He's showing sufficient effort himself to understand it in my opinion.

Comment: @SkonJeet: easy sample to demonstrate both?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10172655/1181338 - pausing iterations    http://stackoverflow.com/a/10173319/1181338 - pausing the UI update

Comment: @SkonJeet, I don't mind ;-) just is helpfull to add that information so everyone will know why not to use a timer.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyLabel.Text = i.ToString();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer to the question?

Comment: @Rippo & RePRO: Why was update not a solution . it will force the control (Label here) to  redraw the invalidated regions within its client area (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: You have a) changed you answer and b) this answer will block the loop from running. I agree it is an answer but its not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BackgroundWoker` class, and it's method `ReportProgress`, do get desired behaviour without locking UI.

```
void backgroundWoker_DoWork(....)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
          backgroundWoker.ReportProgress(0,i.ToString());
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }

}

void backgroundWoker_ProgressChanged(....)
{
     label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? It's a perfectly valid solution, which doesn't envolve locking ui or refering to UI components from a non-ui thread.

Comment: not my downvote, but it seems a heavy-handed and unacceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not good way but you can use:

```
public void test()
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
          label1.Text = i.ToString();
      }
}
```

Comment: This will take 10000 seconds to complete or 30 mins!

Answer (score 0):

sweet and simple

```
DateTime start= DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
 DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
 if( start.Second != end.Second )
 {
  start = end;
  label1.Text = i.ToString();
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

This will allow you see the difference. Set a breakpoint after the loop runs and you will see the array of iz filled with i values. The first one on my machine was at 150000

```
        List<string> iz = new List<string>();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            int zz = 5000;
            int yy = zz / (1 +i);
            zz = yy * i;
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            if (start.Second != end.Second)
            {
                start = end;
                iz.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: @RePRO - Sure it does! That 10000 just flies by in less than a second. Try changing it to longer and you will see. Check my edit out for an easier example to test.

Comment: Bug: if start.Second is 59 the if statement will never be 'true'. You should check 'start.Second <> end.Second'

Comment: Edit: Added Application.DoEvents() call. However this solution has drawbacks.

Comment: @Artemix - Your last comment makes no sense.

Comment: @Travis J - Looks like my edits were not approved. You need to add Application.DoEvents() call after you are changing label.Text. Otherwise the text is not changed until the loop end because UI message queue is not processed. Application.DoEvents() forces message processing and label is repainted. But if you have other interactive controls (like button that was pressed to start the loop) the user will be able to click them again. So you need to disable the 'start' button until loop ends.